# How to turn the site to lightweight mobile version?

Tags: mobile-web-design

Is there some effective way how to turn the complete site into lightweight mobile version (*without creation of special mobile sub-site*) where

- tags on page are reduced only to small subset like `<a>, <img>, <p>, <strong>, <i>, <u>`
- there is a switch `mobile version | standard version` at page footer

Answer (score 1):

This is a very big question. The simplest approach is to implement **responsive technologies** that can work on several devices at the same time.

Joomla 3 has a basic Bootstrap-based template, you can create your own template (implementing any Fluid framework, like Foundation), or you can start with one of the latest templates from a well-known provider.

For specific topics, like "how to deliver different images", there are several techniques. This JAB presentation is very illustrative:

**Right-sizing Images - Mixing Responsive and Adaptive Techniques**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WLoOFqC1NA&index=30&list=PLSwFVRVZ3joTo3InkU_FT65_AK8dQiyZ4

Comment: I'm still considering whether to accept this answer or not. I feel I'm missing something in it. I hesitate that what you suggest might work well on top smartphones but not on cheaper mobiles equipped with browsers with limited abilities. They sometimes cannot successfully load the page because of not supporting something from DOM. Responsive techniques may fail, displaying only blank page etc. So I'm not sure whether delivering resized images and responsive techniques is *enough*. Does this ring any bells? Do you think the answer can be improved in direction I'm speaking about?

Comment: I live in the Third World, surrounded by cheap tablets and mobiles. You can only trust in plain and light Html. Javascript should be optional as you can't be sure if it's going to run. Of course, if you have resources, you could create whole sites for each  device resolution (or/and an App) ... but there are many devices. The long-term effort is not worth. An App decision is sound for specific requirements or mobile optimized experiences.

Comment: Well, so shall I understand the rich content site has to be equipped by standard and mobile template as well as with standard and mobile content? Because there is no more effective approch? I would assume existence of some convertor etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [www.mobilejoomla.com](http://www.mobilejoomla.com/) they seem to specialise in this.

According to their website they claim;

> Mobile Joomla! is the best way to display your Joomla! site on iPhone,
>   iPad, Android & more w/ up to 4x better performance compared to
>   responsive and other mobile templates.

A full list of their features is available [here](http://www.mobilejoomla.com/mobile-joomla-features.html)

I personally don't have eny experience with them so I can't comment, however others may be able to.

They offer custom templates as well as a `mobile version` and `standard version` button links as you have requested. May be worth a look.

Comment: No... mobilejoomla creates a kind of Apps for mobile devices... not related with a lightweight mobile version of a Joomla site.

Comment: @Anibal – I think you misread something because it doesn't create apps, but it is server-side Joomla extension to convert the site into lightweight mobile version. I believe this is a valid answer for my question. Maybe you can consider removal of your downvote.

Comment: @miroxlav I agree, an unnecessary downvote in my opinion.